# "Unable to retrieve logs in Grafana-Loki in the expected format."

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki

I configured Loki with Grafana to monitor logs and I get logs successfully.

Here the issue is in one log I have multiple lines like the below:
[image]

But in Grafana I get each line in log as an individual log like Below:
[image]

This is also not an issue But I want to search anything Like this : {job="qaflogs"} |= `ERROR`

I get only that "ERROR" line like below:
[image]

But I want all lines in one log after searching.

Could someone please assist me with this issue related to Grafana-Loki? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How logs are passed to the Loki? Is it through some library directly from your application, or is it done by Promtail?

Comment: @markalex Thanks for your reply.
I am using Promtail to pass my logs to Loki.

Comment: Look into [multiline](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/multiline/) stage. It allows to capture multiple lines into a single record, and has a couple similar examples in the documentation.

Comment: @markalex can you please give details on how to configure the multiline stage?

Comment: Better that the ones provided in the documentation - no. Your case will be rather similar to first example there.